# How many elements are in the set {(a, b) | (a, b) ∈ N×N and 1 ≤ a ≤ b ≤ n}?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

How many elements are in the set {(a, b) | (a, b) ∈ N×N and 1 ≤ a ≤ b ≤ n}
for n ≥ 1, n ∈ N? Justify your answer.
If you do not know how to solve it for variable n, solve the exercise for n = 5.

Comment: What is giving you trouble -- the notation? It would be good to include these kinds of things in the question, instead of just stating an exercise you were given.

Comment: the problem I am having is to find how many elements are in the set (a,b)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if we take $b$ fixed, there are $b$ possibilites for $(a, b)$ because $1 \leq a \leq b$. $b$ ranges from 1 to $n$, so you want to evaluate $\sum_{i = 1}^ni$.

Comment: so it's $n(n+1)/2$